# Redirect to a specific page on a DNN site with an extensionless URL

Tags: redirect, iis-6, dotnetnuke

I have a page on my DotNetNuke site and I would like to set up a redirect and was wondering the best way to do it. Here is the problem:

I have a page on the site: mydomain.com/dashbaord.aspx. I would like users to be able to type mydomain.com/dashboard OR mydomain.com/Dashboard and it will redirect them to the /dashboard.aspx page.

I have IIS6, so I set up wildcard mapping, and it seemed to work for /dashboard, but not /Dashboard. Also, I am looking for it to literally redirect you so that /dashbaord.aspx shows up in the address bar. In addition, the wildcard mapping broke some other links on the site, so I was looking for an alternative method to accomplish this. Is there a way that I can set this up through IIS? Or any other way?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, create a virtual directory by right clicking on Sites, and then call it Dashboard. Then set that to redirect to a specific URL, in your case, http://mydomain.com/dashboard.aspx.

Comment: When I go to add a virtual directory, it asks for a path, as in a server file path. There is no option to set a specific URL. Am I missing something?... After adding the alias of "Dashboard", I am presented with this screen: http://screencast.com/t/bwCgI0LUj9D

Comment: Joe - pick any path at first, like C:/, then create the virtual directory, edit it again, and then you can change to a URL